# How to execute pipe hidden C++

Tags: c++, console, pipe

I have a C++ program for Windows in which I need to know the type of graphics card the user has.

The way I obtain it is by executing this pipe command

```
std::shared_ptr<FILE> pipe(_popen("wmic path win32_VideoController get name", "r"), _pclose);
```

This causes a brief console window to flash.

How can I execute this pipe command without the console window displaying? Makes my program look glitchy in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify your code to query WMI directly using the WMI API instead of invoking an external console.

Have a look at this example (there is one for C++): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa391398(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Definitely the way to go. Thank you for this, however I'm super confused how to use this. Like in the sample C++ code on that site, where is the buffer holding the result text? Would you be able to write up a quick sample? I'd love you forever :D

Comment: @mocode9 The example was for executing a WQL query which may return one ore multiple results. The example then goes to show how to iterate over the resultset. There was no one buffer to hold the result text. That's what you'd be putting in. Does that make sense?